# Jquery add animation to add/removeClass and clone/remove elements

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, animation

I'd like to add an animation (possibly the same) to the add/removeClass and clone/remove elements. For the add/removeClass function I tried to use the bootstrap class "fade in" (with no success). For clone/remove elements I tried to use hide/show (success only remove)

HTML

```
<!-- CLONE BTN -->
<div class="row cust-gutters">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <span id="cloneRow" class="label label-primary pointer">
            Add <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="clonable-row-label hide fade">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label class="control-label" for="phone">Phone</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clonable-row hide fade">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="phone[]" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash deleteRow" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$("#cloneRow").on('click', function() {
    var num = $(".clonable-row").length;
    if($(".clonable-row:first").hasClass("hide")) {
        $(".clonable-row:first, .clonable-row-label").addClass("in");
        $(".clonable-row:first, .clonable-row-label").removeClass("hide");
    } else {
        if(num < 4) {
            //var row = $('.clonable-row:first').clone(true);
            //row.insertAfter('.clonable-row:last').show().fadeIn(600);
            $(".clonable-row:first").clone(true).insertAfter(".clonable-row:last");
        }
    }
});

$(".deleteRow").on('click', function() {
    var num = $(".clonable-row").length;
    if(num == 1) {
        $('.clonable-row-label').addClass("hide").removeClass("in");
        $(this).closest('.clonable-row').addClass("hide").removeClass("in");
    } else {
        $(this).closest('.clonable-row').hide(600, function() {
            $(this).closest('.clonable-row').remove();
        });
    }
});
```

How could I do it?
Thank You

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/oagw16hc/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery UI provides animated versions of [.addClass()](http://api.jqueryui.com/addclass/) and [removeClass()](http://api.jqueryui.com/removeclass/).

As for animating when showing an element, you should go with *fadeIn()*, as you have. Be aware that fadeIn() ALREADY shows() such element, so doing something like $(element).show().fadeIn() is pointless, as when fadeIn() begins, the element will be already displayed, and $(element).fadeIn().show() is also pointless, as fadeIn(), on completion, will already fully display the element.

The problem with the following snippet is conceptual:

```
$(this).closest('.clonable-row').hide(600, function() {
    $(this).closest('.clonable-row').remove();
});
```

It should go this way:

```
$(this).closest('.clonable-row').hide(600, function() {
    // Note here that $(this) is already the element (jQuery-wrapped) you called .hide() on
    $(this).remove();
});
```

**EDIT**

For your specific case, inserting the cloned element, you should hide it before inserting it in your HTML:

```
$(".clonable-row:first").clone(true).hide().insertAfter(".clonable-row:last").fadeIn();
```

Comment: Now animation of clone is perfect! But I still have problems with the animation of the add/removeclass with jquery ui https://jsfiddle.net/oagw16hc/13/  Tnahks

Comment: Here it goes:

Line 18 of your fiddle adds _hide_ class to a div that is a container of the _.clonable-row-label_ you are selecting:
       `$(this).closest('.clonable-row').addClass("hide");`
The problem here is that the outer div will be instantly hidden, when the animated .addClass() on _.clonable-row-label_ won't have finished. That line should be in a callback (on complete) of the animated call to .addClass().

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

$(".clonable-row:first").clone(true).insertAfter(".clonable-row:last").hide().fadeIn(600);

Comment: I've done a test, on second iteration (i've added my test in else), here: http://jsfiddle.net/oagw16hc/11/